# Как выводить номер для каждого вызова метода?

Tags: java

Программа должна выводить несколько void методов. Как сделать так, чтобы при каждом выводе эта строчка получала номер? Я понимаю, что надо использовать цикл, но не пойму как именно его использовать.

Код:

```
public class Parrot extends Pet {
    private int age;

    public Parrot(int size, String name, int age ) {

        super(size, name);

        this.age = age;
        }

    void eat() {    
    }
    void fly () {
        System.out.println("It can fly very high");
    }
    void getWordsPerDay (int words) {
        System.out.println("It can pronounce " + words + " words per day");
    }
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы заданные методы каждый раз при вызове получали порядковый номер?

Например, если вызываются методы `eat(), eat(), fly(), eat(), fly()`, то выводится `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`.

Comment: что значит получала номер? Типо 1 It can fly very high, 2 It can fly very high?

Comment: Нужны пояснения, что именно требуется достигнуть. Например 1) нужно чтобы каждый метод выводил свой номер фиксированный? Т.е. eat() всегда выводил 1, fly() всегда 2... 2) Нужно чтобы каждый метод имел свою отдельную нумерацию. Например первый вызов eat() выводил 1, второй 2 и т.д. А первый вызов flu() выводил 1, второй 2 и т.д. 3) Нужно чтобы была нумерация общая для вызова любого метода т.е. если вызываю eat(), eat(), fly(), eat(), fly(), то выводилось бы 1 2 3 4 5.

Comment: да, именно так, как вы описали: чтобы при вызове метода автоматически ставился нужный порядковый номер

Comment: то есть третий вариант ответа

Answer (score 2):

Прямолинейный подход: создать метод, который увеличивает и выводит значение счетчика и вызывать его в каждом из методов:

```
public class Parrot extends Pet {

     /**
     * Счетчик
     */
     private int callCounter = 0;

     /**
     * Увеличивает и выводит счетчик
     */
     private void countCall() {
         callCounter++;
         System.out.println(callCounter);      
     }

     void eat() {
         countCall();
         ...
     }

     void fly() {
         countCall();
         ... 
     }
```

Если нужно, чтобы счетчик был общим для разных объектов `Parrot`, то `callCounter` и `countCall` нужно будет объявить как `static`.

Этот способ требует изменения кода всех методов, по которым нужно считать вызовы. Если по каким-то причинам нужно считать вызовы не изменяя кода, то задача усложняется. Есть следующие варианты:

- Чтобы считать вызовы для «чужого» класса, можно [обернуть](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)) его в свой и считать вызовы в обертке.
- Если нужно автоматизировать процесс, например, отслеживать все вызовы методов по определенным критериям, то можно воспользоваться методами [аспектно-ориентированного программирования](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). Одна из реализаций для Java: [AspectJ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AspectJ).

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы сделать то, что вы хотите достаточно завести статическую переменную и обращаться к ней каждый раз при вызове метода. Но здесь есть один нюанс, если методы вызываются из разных потоков, нужно объявить ее соответствующим потокобезопасным примитивом:

```
private static final AtomicLong atomicCounter = new AtomicLong(0);
```

либо обернуть в `java.lang.ThreadLocal`:

```
private static final ThreadLocal<Long> threadLocalCounter = new ThreadLocal<>();
```

Тела методов будут выглядеть соотвественно так:

```
public void firstMethod() {
    System.out.println(atomicCounter.getAndIncrement());
}
```

либо:

```
public void firstMethod() {
    long value = threadLocalCounter.get();
    System.out.println(value);
    threadLocalCounter.set(value + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

если хочешь поставить счетчик вызова каждого метода, то можно сделать так:

```
public class Parrot extends Pet {
    private int age;
    private int countFly = 0;
    private int countgetWordsPerDay = 0;

    public Parrot(int size, String name, int age ) {

        super(size, name);

        this.age = age;
        }

    void eat() {    
    }
    void fly () {
        countFly = countFly + 1;
        System.out.println(countFly + ")" + "It can fly very high");        
    }
    void getWordsPerDay (int words) {
        System.out.println(countgetWordsPerDay + ")" + "It can pronounce " + words + " words per day");
    }
}
```

Comment: только что попробовала данный код: выводятся два ноля на последних методах, а мне надо, чтобы выводилось по очереди 1,2,3,4 и так далее (в зависимости от количества методов или количества их вызовов

Comment: ну конечно, я забыл указать ТИП переменной, укажи тип переменных, например int, либо скопируй код выше (я поправил)

Comment: все должно теперь работать